Удаляется первое введенное слово в поиске браузера firefox
Удаляется первое введенное слово после нажатия пробела в поиске браузера firefox (при чем происходит это не всегда).
В остальном все работает как обычно. Проблемы так же нет и в других браузерах.
Происходит такое с самого начала пользования - купил новый ноутбук без ОС, установил Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

Поддерживаю вопрос. У меня тоже самое.

У меня была такая же проблема: первое слово в строке поиска постоянно удалялось, если же искать через адресную строку, всё работало.
Исправил так:
Ввел в адресной строке about:config
Нажал "Принять риск и продолжить"
Нашёл в открывшемся списке параметр browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.improvesearch.handoffToAwesomebar
Изменил значение на False
Так-то этот параметр просто отключает перенаправление запросов из строки поиска в адресную строку, но у меня вместе с этим исправилась и эта проблема.
